# Running exe from ASPX page and returning output

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code to execute exe from the ASPX page,

```
        string path = @"C:\Reshma\DATA\bbc1.pdf";
        System.Diagnostics.Process si = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        si.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\";
        si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        si.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.bbc.com"+" "+path;
        si.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        si.Start();
        si.WaitForExit();
        string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        si.Close();
        Response.Write(output);
```

My problem is program doesnot exit and it doesnot renders output. I am trying to convert the webpage into pdf by passing 2 arguments. bbc1.pdf originates in the respective path but without any content.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint at the line string.output what occurs?